# Read Dir PHP / Echo file contents within <li></li>

Tags: php, include, directory

**In Short:** Im trying to make a latest news scroller for a website that will read a directories .txt files, and then display their contents within 'li' tags. Allowing me to add a file manager in which i can upload multiple text files to and have them displayed properly within the scroller script.

**In Length:**

Im using this script to read and display the files within the directory:

```
<?php
$dir = 'latest';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $ind_file){
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $dir."/".$ind_file;?>"><?php echo $ind_file;?></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

But that only displays a list of the .txt files in the directory.

Id like to read and display the contents of the .txt files in individual 'li' tags, much the same way as php include does:

```
<?php include ('file.txt'); ?>
```

The reason for needing this format is for use within [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/sagscroller.htm) script.

I dont know enough about php to 'wing it' as everything i've tried has failed, so if anyone knows how to write this properly or knows of a better way of accomplishing this, im open to all ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dir = 'latest';
foreach (glob("$dir/*.txt") as $filename) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo "<li>$contents</li>";      
}
```

Check [glob documentation](http://php.net/glob) to adopt this script for your needs.

Comment: Hole in one mate. Thanks very much for your help and being so prompt. Cheers.